# Как поместить один виджет поверх другого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

В главный контейнер `main_box` попадают кнопка `btn` и цветной контейнер `box`.

В `box` я добавляю четыре виджета:

1. `self.back_picture` - изображение, которое располагается в верхней части контейнера, полученное с помощью класса `BackPicture`. 
   Кнопка `btn`, привязанная к методу `remake` класса `MyWindow`, меняет картинку в `self.back_picture`. 
   Это очень важно, так как говорит о непостоянности содержимого `self.back_picture`.
2. `self.round_picture` - изображение с закругленными краями, полученное с помощью класса `RoundPicture`. Подобно `self.back_picture`, картинка в `self.round_picture` будет в дальнейшем меняться. Я не стал добавлять эту возможность сейчас, чтобы не загромождать код.
3. **`Два`** виджета `QLabel` - `label1` и `label2`, которые не выполняют никаких прямых функций, но нужны для понимания того, как контейнер `box` располагает внутри себя виджеты.

Окно приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нарисовал схему того, что мне теперь нужно (ниже будет описание):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. `round_picture` располагается над `back_picture`.
2. Расстояние между левой границей `box` и `round_picture` равно расстоянию между `round_picture` и правой границей `box`. Эти расстояния постоянны.
3. `back_picture` остается на своем месте - в самом верху контейнера `box1`. Между верхней границей  `box` и виджетом **нет абсолютно никакого** расстояния. Так должно быть при любом размере окна.
4. Между `round_picture` и верхней границей `box1` добавляется растяжимое пространство stretch = 3.
5. Между `round_picture` и `label1` добавляется растяжимое пространство stretch = 3.
6. Между `label1` и `label2` добавляется растяжимое пространство stretch = 1.
7. Между `label2` и нижней границей `box1` добавляется растяжимое пространство stretch = 3.
8. Возможность менять картинки на `round_picture` и `back_picture` должна сохраниться.

Фон виджетам `label1` и `label2` на схеме я добавил, чтобы было лучше видно. В реальности фона нет, но он и не нужен.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне расположить виджеты так, как я описал.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 15 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)
        main_box.addWidget(btn)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('picture3.jpg', 300)       
        box.addWidget(self.back_picture, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.round_picture = RoundPicture('picture1.png', 150)
        self.round_picture.setStyleSheet('background: transparent;')
        box.addWidget(self.round_picture, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 2')
        label2.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.setStretch(0, 0)
        box.setStretch(1, 2)
        box.setStretch(2, 2)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture2.png')
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('picture3.jpg')
            self.index = 1


qss = '''QLabel {
             color: red;
             font: bold 16px;
             background: transparent;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я убрал `back_picture` из макета.  Попробуйте что получилось.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 15 
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, 
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class BackPicture(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackPicture, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #2A303D;')
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)                                  # box1  ??? 
        main_box.addWidget(btn)        
        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.back_picture = BackPicture('300_300.png', 300, self.container)      # + , self.container
#        box.addWidget(self.back_picture, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)     # ---
        self.back_picture.move(0, 0)                                             # +++

        box.addStretch(3)                                                         # +++

        self.round_picture = RoundPicture('head2.jpg', 150)                       
        self.round_picture.setStyleSheet('background: transparent;')
        box.addWidget(self.round_picture, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.addStretch(3)                                                         # +++

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 1')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.addStretch(1)                                                         # +++

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text number 2')
        label2.setStyleSheet(qss)
        box.addWidget(label2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        box.addStretch(3)                                                          # +++


        '''
#        box.setStretch(0, 0)
        box.setStretch(0, 3)      # ?

        box.setStretch(1, 2)
        box.setStretch(2, 2)

        box.setStretch(3, 2)       # ?
        '''

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('background.png') 
            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.back_picture.setPicture('300_300.png') 
            self.index = 1


qss = '''QLabel {
             color: red;
             font: bold 16px;
             background: transparent;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Сейчас я понял, что деталь, которую я вчера забыл предусмотреть, совсем тут не нужна :)  Мне не стоило закрывать вопрос

Answer (score 2):

В режиме редактирования файла ресурсов и ui-файла (QtCreator)

1. Добавляете картинку в файл ресурсов проекта (файл qrs).
2. В режиме редактирования ui-файла выбираете любой виджет и в панеле настроек
   находите и нажимаете (на кнопку с тремя точками) в пункте `styleSheet`
3. Там, в выпадающем меню `"Добавить ресурс"`, выбираете background-image
4. Слева выбираете `"<Resource Root>"` - справа появятся соответствующие картинки из файла ресурсов. Выбираете необходимую картинку.
5. В поле qss появится следующая запись `background-image: url(...);` которую удаляете, предварительно скопировав url(...)
6. Далее вводите следующую строку

```
#<имя переменной вашего виджета> {
    border-image: url(:</path/to/the/picture.ext>) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
```

таким образом вы заполните вашей картинкой весь фон конкретного виджета.
Для пропорционального заполнения - поиграйтесь с параметрами border-image, или размерами самого виджета

**NB**. Без задания имени переменной виджета `#<имя переменной вашего виджета>` картинка станет фоном у всех дочерних виджетов данного виджета

Comment: Большое спасибо. К сожалению, я не могу отметить второй ответ правильным :(

Comment: @MAXIM045 все нормально, я видел, что уже есть правильный ответ, просто описал альтернативный вариант. Можете подарить мне за труды 10 очков, нажав на стрелочку вверх :))

Comment: Я уже давно нажал на стрелочку :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 Благодарю!